# VNC package details for ubuntu 16.04 for ARM platform

Tags: 16.04, vnc, arm

What is the package name of VNC for ARM ubuntu 16.04?

Kindly share the details of VNC package details for ubuntu 16.04 (ARM FileSystem).

Comment: "ARM FileSystem"? What is that? Which VNC client are you asking about? Or are you talking about VNC servers?

Comment: Anyway, list of packages with vnc in their name available for armhf and arm64: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=arm64,armhf&keywords=vnc

Comment: I have ubuntu 16.04 filesystem running on my ARM Embedded device and have installed x11vnc server.  I am not able to connect to embedded device using vnc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ARM is not a FileSystem but a type of Architecture. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture):

> ARM, originally Acorn RISC Machine, later Advanced RISC Machine, is a
>   family of reduced instruction set computing (RISC) architectures for
>   computer processors, configured for various environments.

---

Now, to the package:

A quick search at [Ubuntu Packages Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=arm64&searchon=names&keywords=vnc) gives us the list of packages with regex `vnc`. Now, depending on your requirements, you may install your required package.